# Configure settings for testing mail sending with localhost and orchard

Tags: email, localhost, orchardcms

I have installed and enabled the Email module in Orchard, and used the settings given in orchard documentation for the set up(someemail@email.com, host name: 127.0.0.1 and port number 25). Yet, no email is sent. I have searched for a correct way to do it. If somebody has managed to get Orchard CMS to work with sending email for testing on localhost, please shear.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use your own email to send test emails? You can easily find the host name and port stuff you need on your provider's (eg gmail) website

Comment: What do you mean "installed"? It comes standard, there's nothing to install.

Comment: We are making many custom modules, so some of the modules have been removed and we add them on the fly as we need them. :)

Comment: For testing purposes [Smtp4Dev](https://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/) comes in quite handy.